# MaterialAlertDialog Transparent Background

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog

I use the material design component for alert dialog, I want a transparent black background color, but there is something strange in the backgound, there is a little white color, how to solve this problem. please the solution.

[image]

This style.xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>


<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="colorSurface">#C1121212</item>
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/BodyTextStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded</item>
</style>
<style name="TitleTextStyle" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fafafa</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
<style name="BodyTextStyle" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">#c7c7c7</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
<style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#d81b60</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">#ad1457</item>
</style>
<style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#757575</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">#a4a4a4</item>
</style>
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">14dp</item>
</style>
```

this Activity

```
binding.snack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Objects.requireNonNull(new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(RegisterActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme)
                    .setTitle("Dialog")
                    .setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .show());

        }
    });
```

Comment: is AlertDialogTheme inheriting some padding or margins?

Comment: it does'nt inherit

Comment: what about  parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog"?

Comment: show your xml file

Comment: I have edited my post, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the background with your colorSurface as a ColorDrawable:

```
setBackground(ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#C1121212")))
```

So it will look like this:

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(RegisterActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme)
        .setTitle("Dialog")
        .setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setBackground(ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#C1121212")))
        .show();
```